# Change the HTML tag on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a customer form for a project, and while I display them i want the user to be able to click on a button to edit the customer's data.
Here is the thing I need:

```
<span>Customer_name</span>
<span>Customer_surname</span>
<span>...</span>
<button>Click me to turn spans into inputs</button>
```

When the user click on the button, I want the spans to turn into inputs.
Any help will be apreciated!

Comment: You can have input box there and they will be hidden by default. Then when user clicks on button show the input box and hide the span.

Comment: I was thinking doing that, will that be a correct way though? I thought maybe there is a javascript function doing something like that. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Use can also remove span and create a new input to replace it

Comment: Alright, that's what I will probably do

Comment: @petrosg: if you would like to do it without any library in native javascript.
I have added an answer below with working fiddle. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in native javascript..

Hope it helps

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#span-container > div");

 document.getElementById("toggle-btn").addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(var i=0; i< elems.length; i++) {

        if(elems[i].firstElementChild.className.indexOf("see") === -1) {

            elems[i].firstElementChild.className = elems[i].lastElementChild.className += "see";
            elems[i].lastElementChild.value = elems[i].firstElementChild.innerText;

        } else {

            elems[i].firstElementChild.className = elems[i].lastElementChild.className = "";
            elems[i].firstElementChild.innerText = elems[i].lastElementChild.value;

        }
     }
 })
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#span-container > div {
  width: 200px;
  height:30px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#span-container > div span{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#span-container > div input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#span-container > div span.see {
  display: none;
}
#span-container > div input.see {
  display: block;
}

button {
  padding: 4px 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="span-container">
   <div>
      <span>Customer_name</span>
      <input type="text" />   
   </div>
  <div>
      <span>Customer_surname</span>
      <input type="text" />   
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Customer_surname</span>
    <input type="text" />   
  </div>  
</div>
<button id="toggle-btn">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks very very much mate, I used this and worked perfect, just as i wanted to. Apreciate it very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="customerdata">
    <span>Customer_name</span>
    <span>Customer_surname</span>
    <span>...</span>
    <button class="editbtn">Click me to turn spans into inputs</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(document).on("click",'.editbtn',function (){
        $(this).closest(".customerdata").find('span').attr("contenteditable","true");
    });

});
```

[fiddlelink](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/npzo8h03/)

Comment: Exactly what i wanted!! I will try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Check [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qcbvL7dv/18/)

```
$('button').click(function()
    {

     $('span').each(function()
     {
     $(this).context.innerHTML="";
     $(this).context.innerHTML='<input type= text id = textBox></input>';
     }) 

    });
```